# Storage Pool - Lost Communcation

Tags: windows, powershell, storage, pool

I have a big problem with my storage pool.

Namely I have 7 hard drives in my pool in Windows 10. Now two of them have been disconnected and after I reconnected them I get the message "Warning". In PowerShell I get "Lost Communication" for these two disks. How can I add them again without data loss?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PhysicalDisk

DeviceId FriendlyName                          SerialNumber   MediaType   CanPool OperationalStatus  HealthStatus Usage            Size
-------- ------------                          ------------   ---------   ------- -----------------  ------------ -----            ----
5        ST8000DM004-2CX188                    ZCT039J7       HDD         False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select   7.28 TB
0        ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z                   Z8416XR7       HDD         False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select   7.28 TB
3        ATA Crucial_CT750MX3                  16161312104B   SSD         False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select 698.64 GB
         ST8000AS 0002-1NA17Z SCSI Disk Device Z840KHSV       HDD         False   Lost Communication Warning      Auto-Select   7.28 TB
1        TOSHIBA MD04ACA400 SCSI Disk Device   15Q3KFPLFSAA   HDD         False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
7        SAMSUNG HD501LJ                       S0MUJ1CQA11444 Unspecified False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select 465.76 GB
6        SAMSUNG HD103SI                       S1Y5J1KS904807 Unspecified False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select 931.51 GB
2        ST8000AS 0002-1NA17Z SCSI Disk Device Z840F1JP       HDD         False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select   7.28 TB
4        TOSHIBA HDWE140 SCSI Disk Device      95CEKHKQF58D   HDD         False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
         WDC WD80EZAZ-11TDBA0                                 HDD         False   Lost Communication Warning      Auto-Select   7.28 TB
```

---

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-VirtualDisk

FriendlyName     ResiliencySettingName FaultDomainRedundancy OperationalStatus                     HealthStatus  Size FootprintOnPool StorageEfficiency
------------     --------------------- --------------------- -----------------                     ------------  ---- --------------- -----------------
Datenfestplatten Parity
```

Comment: Can nobody help me?